# Why the GPU will cost more time when train the net

Tags: neural-networks, gpu

I'm in *Windows 10*

```
$Version
```

> `11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)`

---

```
net = LinearLayer[];
AbsoluteTiming[
 trained = NetTrain[net, {1 -> 1.9, 2 -> 4.1, 3 -> 6.0, 4 -> 8.1}]]
```

[image]

```
net = LinearLayer[];
AbsoluteTiming[
 trained = NetTrain[net, {1 -> 1.9, 2 -> 4.1, 3 -> 6.0, 4 -> 8.1},TargetDevice -> "GPU"]]
```

[image]

I can reproduce this case,but actually I have a very powerfull gpu as you see

```
Needs["MXNetLink`"];
MXNetLink`PackageScope`getGPUInformation[]
```

> `{<|TotalMemory->-2147483648,ComputeCapability->61/10,Name->GeForce GTX1060|>}`

Do I have triggered the bug of *MMA*? I'm in the `v11.2`. Can anyone reproduce it?

Comment: GPUs are good at performing the same calculations on large arrays. Training a single linear mapping may well be slower on the GPU. If you train networks with millions of parameters, the GPU is much much faster, in my experience. I don't think this is a bug.

Comment: What @nikie says one with caveat: training/inference is only fast if all activation maps and gradients fit in GPU memory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948406/why-is-my-gpu-slower-than-cpu-when-training-lstm-rnn-models

Comment: Actually simply increasing the size of the training data, thus allowing larger batch size, makes the GPU training faster. Try this `NetTrain[net, RandomReal[1, 10^5] -> RandomReal[1, 10^5]]`. GPUs are only better than CPUs when a lot of computations can be done in parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> actually I have a very powerfull gpu as you see

Sorry for the car analogy, but the best way to think if this is: Picture your CPU as a Ferrari race car, and your GPU as a passenger train. If you want to transport one or two people from A to B, the race car is much faster. With the train, you have to get to the station, buy a ticket, wait until the train departs and so on. The race car will easily be 5-10 times faster.

*But* if you want to transport 1000 people from A to B, the race car will have to make 500 trips back and forth - the train on the other hand can transport 1000 people in one trip. So the train is 50-100 times faster now.

Moral: Only use the GPU if you have large amounts of data that have to be processed with more or less the same code.

Comment: First time to hear such analogy. It is vivid..